# Connect two network hierarchies together automatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network

I have two Networks as line shapefiles. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZacF.png) is a secondary road network and [2] is a highway network. The sources of the files are different, which is why the connection of the two is not trivial. Also, the two networks have varying travelspeed attributes which ought to be preserved.

I know where the access and egress points of the highway network to the secondary network is. I'm unable to find an automated approach to this problem though (there are about 100 access/eggress points).

As you can see in the example image a simple "Feature to Line" operation would not work, as the highway "intersects" with the secondary network and in this operation, the access and egress points would be ignored.

Is there a way to automatically unite the two networks using, e.g. a search radius around the access points to snap to the secondary road network?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the near table from high ways, as well as the secondary road network to the intersection centroid and then proceeded as the model below is showing:

[image]